# How to scrape values which are not present by putting "-"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was scraping movies from IMDB website. While scraping, I was able to scrape the certificate for the movie, i.e. is it banned, or is it PG-13, or is it R, but seems like for some of the movies, certificate is not present, so how do I put "-" for those movies, I tried using if-else loop as seen in the code below but it did not seem to work. Attaching the code and screenshot for reference. I am using BeautifulSoup library for scraping. Is there a way we can put "-" or "NA" in place where it is not present

```
if data.find_all("span",{"class":"certificate"}):
    certificate=[c.get_text() for c in data.find_all("span",{"class":"certificate"})]
else:
    certificate="-"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share URL of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Search for the parent of the `span` class (the `<p class="text-muted">`), and *then* check if the `span` tag with class `certificate` exists.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=action&genres=Action"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"user-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for p in soup.find_all("p", {"class": "text-muted"}):
    if p.find("span", {"class":"certificate"}):
        certificate = p.span.get_text()
    else:
        certificate = "-"
    print(certificate)
```

```
TV-MA
-
PG-13
-
TV-14
-
PG-13
...
...
```

Comment: hey, what does the headers={"user-Agent":"curl/10.20.88"} really do in fourth line?

Comment: User agent can be used to request pages from the server in a certain predefined style (desktop, mobile, etc). In this case it was just an agent from a previous project I had. I will edit to a more common agent to avoid any issues.